# How do I pass a query results from a subform to a report using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Subform which has a datasheet, a textbox and a button. I want to be able to input the records on the datasheet onto a report using the value on the textbox by clicking the subform button.

The report has a record source linked to query qryrpt. If I put a criteria on the qrypt, it keeps asking for a parameter to be entered. I want to avoid this since the parameter is the same as the value on the subform textbox. Is there a better way of doing this? Could someone please point me to the right direction?

```
Private Sub createreport_Click()

Dim Task As String
Dim SearchResults

Me.txtSearch.Value = Me.SearchResults
Task = "SELECT * FROM tblA WHERE ((Location Like ""*" & SearchResults & 
"*""))"

Me.frmDatasheet.Form.RecordSource = Task

Me.SearchResults.Value = Reports!rptName.txtheading
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptName", acViewPreview

End Sub
```

Comment: Either have the parameter in query reference form control or apply filter criteria with OpenReport command: `DoCmd.OpenReport "rptName", acViewPreview, , "Location LIKE '*" & SearchResults & "*'"`

Comment: @June7 I have tried that but the i keep getting the error report is misspelled or does not exist.

Comment: So what is name of report?

Comment: Thanks June7, also i found out that if i use: 
     If Application.CurrentProject.AllReports("rptName").IsLoaded = True Then DoCmd.OpenReportt "rptName", acViewPreview, , "Location LIKE '*" & SearchResults & "*'" End If    works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @june7 suggested is one possibility

I would rather approach differently

create a query and save as `reportQuery_Task` with a query as below

```
SELECT * FROM tblA
```

use this query as a Recordsource in your report `rptName`

```
Private Sub createreport_Click()

Dim Task As String
Dim SearchResults


Me.txtSearch.Value = Me.SearchResults
Task = "SELECT * FROM tblA WHERE ((Location Like ""*" & SearchResults & 
"*""))"

Me.frmDatasheet.Form.RecordSource = Task

'used this to change your query at run time based on the user selected criteria.
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("reportQuery_Task").sql = Task

Me.SearchResults.Value = Reports!rptName.txtheading
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptName", acViewPreview

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I did just go through this myself.  Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452920/access-abends-after-docmd-openreport).  Using the subform's button's _Click Event Procedure, use DoCmd's last parameter OpenArgs to send a prebuilt delimited list (recordset first followed by other parameteres) with the .OpenReport procedure.  In the report's _Open Event Procedure use Split with the aforementioned delimiter to breakout your parameters appropriately.